# Example of alternative to TransactionCompleted event?

Tags: .net, transactions, system.transactions

From the [MSDN entry for TransactionCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted.aspx):

> You can register for this event instead of using a volatile enlistment to get outcome information for transactions.
>
> **Caution** Signing up for this event negatively affects the performance of the transaction it is attached to.

Does anyone have an example, or even an explanation, of how to enlist in a transaction so as merely to be notified of its completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN might be a bit misleading here. Registering the event should be at least as fast as enlisting a dummy resource manager (not that I've tested it).

The thing is, if you enlist, the transaction will become a distributed one (since there are now at least two resource managers involved). Such a transaction is slower (more IO with the database server or what ever you work with).

You can still try the enlist way. Just implement `IEnlistmentNotification` and call `enlistment.Done()` in every method. You'll also want to add your code to the `Commit()` method.

Then pass the reference to your implementation to the transaction's `EnlistVolatile(..)` method (with options set to `None`).

Comment: The transaction will only become distributed if more than one *durable* resource manager enlists.  `EnlistVolatile` will never promote the transaction.